# How to set separate session for multiple query execution under single connection on hikari,

Tags: spring-boot, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, hikaricp

I have single getConnection to my snowflake and executing the multiple queries  gives same session id

I want to create separate session id for each query executed under single getConnection How to do this ?

I am using snowflake ,spring boot application and hikariCP

Answer (score 0):

The getConnection API will create a session, it's a single connection which you get from pools of connections.

This connection can not be further divided.

For your scenario, you can call multiple getConnection API for multiple sessions and then use each session for each SQL query execution.

In the configuration file, you can set the max and min values for connections in the pool.

Please refer to this link for more details

https://www.cloudnativemaster.com/post/how-to-create-a-jdbc-connection-pool-based-on-hikaricp-cache-using-guava-cache-in-springboot